# How do I create (and use) an array of pointers to an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I need to create an array of pointers that will each point to an array of strings.
The base, is a size 2 array of strings (the length of the strings is unknown at start). For example an array of 2 strings (first-name and last-name):

```
char *name[2];
```

Now I need to create an array of an unknown size (entered by the user) that will point to the type that I just created.
My idea was to create it this way:

```
char **people=name;
```

And then ask the user how many names he would like to enter and allocate enough space to hold all the names.

```
people=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*num); //num is the number received by the user.
```

This is where things got too complicated to me and I can't figure out how to I call each individual name to put a string in it.
I built a loop that will receive all the names but I have no idea how to store them properly.

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    printf("Please enter the #%d first and last name:\n",i+1);
    //Receives the first name.
    scanf("%s",&bufferFirstName);
    getchar();
    //Receives the last name (can also include spaces).
    gets(bufferLastName);
    people[i][0]=(char*)malloc(strlen(bufferFirstName)+1);
    people[i][1]=(char*)malloc(strlen(bufferLastName)+1);
    //^^Needless to say that it won't even compile :(
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to properly use this kind of an array of points?
Thanks.

Comment: `people[i][0]=(char*)malloc(strlen(bufferFirstName)+1);` is wrong. if `people` is a `char**` then `people[0]` is a `char*` and `people[i][0]` is a `char`. Not a pointer. Also: don't cast malloc()s return value. It is not needed and possibly dangerous, since it can hide errors.

Comment: So `people` should be a `***` type instead of `**` (`char ***people`)? Also, is there a way of defining `people` in one line without the use of `*name[2]`?

Comment: From the question it is not clear what is your intention. I just point out the obvious error(s). And in most cases: when you start thinking of `***` you should consider using structs (like in @msider(s) answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/):

> declare foo as array of pointer to array 2 of pointer to char

```
char *(*foo[])[2];
```

So, `foo[0]` is a pointer to array 2 of `char *`

That is the array, but for your use, you want:

> declare foo as pointer to array 2 of pointer to char;

```
char *(*foo)[2];
```

Now you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *(*foo)[2];

    printf("How many people?\n");
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);

    foo = malloc(sizeof *foo * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char bufFirstName[1024];
        char bufLastName[1024];

        printf("Please insert the #%d first and last name:\n", i+1);

        scanf("%s %s", bufFirstName, bufLastName); 

        char *firstName = malloc(strlen(bufFirstName) + 1);
        char *lastName = malloc(strlen(bufLastName) + 1);

        strcpy(firstName, bufFirstName);
        strcpy(lastName, bufLastName);

        foo[i][0] = firstName;
        foo[i][1] = lastName;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s LastName: %s\n", foo[i][0], foo[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-std=c99`

Note that using `scanf`, `strcpy`, `strlen` like that is unsafe because there can be a buffer overflow.

Also, remember to free your malloc's!

Comment: When I'm trying to use it, it shows an error "Error: Incomplete type is not allowed".

Comment: It was when I tried using `char *(*foo[])[2];` (before you edited the post).

Comment: Sorry, the first thing is the actual answer to your question (that's what you asked :P). The rest of the post is what I think that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have finally managed to get something going after hours of frustration XD.

Answer (score 0):

**Not** that your approach is wrong, but have you considered instead using a struct that includes first and last name, and then malloc'ing based on the number of names the user will enter:

```
typedef struct {
    char* first;
    char* last;
} person;

person* people = malloc(num * sizeof(*person));
```

This just simplifies pointer interaction. While the way you are doing it **is** a good exercise in understanding pointers better, it may not be the easiest way to understand.

If you are unable to use `structs`, you should instead be doing:

```
char** people;  
people = malloc(2*num*sizeof(char*));  

for (int i = 0; i < 2*num; i++) 
    people[i] = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE*sizeof(char));
```

Now you would need to reference the i *th* person via:

```
first name: people[i*2 + 0] 
last name: people[i*2 + 1]
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use `***`.

Comment: BTW: the downvote was mine, unintentionally, must have been a clicko. The silly CMS does not allow me to correct it. yet.

Comment: No worries, I thought it must have been a mistake by someone as it was downvoted almost instantly as I posted it.

Comment: The line `people[i][0] = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE*sizeof(char));` shows an error "Error: a value type "char*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char"".

Comment: Woops, yeah I had a mistake there, but it's fixed now. @Marco has a good solution.